# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at main function with lack of tracing information

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access

- I run the code on iOS Simulator. The game will always crushed at popping up Apple purchase window (like buying something in the application), and indicating a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" at the main function.
- Then I run the code with Instruments, like Zombie, the game crushed but Zombie does not report error nor show the stack trace.
- Neither Xcode console provide enough information for me.

I hope someone could explain what should I do in this case. Is there any way that I can get more stack trace information?

Comment: If Zombies can't find it you should really step through the code that you feel is the problem until you find the exact line. Unfortunately you won't get a good print out if it shows you are crashing in main. You should basically ignore the fact that its showing a breakpoint there and just assume the problem is in your code.

Comment: In your project, set up an exception breakpoint. That way, the app will stop or break where ever the app crashes and you can infact see the stack there and you will get much better debug info. The way to set up an exception break point is to go to the Breakpoint navigator window and on the lower left there is a + sign, click on it and select "Add Exception breakpoint" and then run your program again.